# Can I do both javascript and a PHP form?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to take advantage of some jquery functions for sending messages like having a modal dialog but I also want to include users not running javascript.

If I have a jquery function to handle the dialog but the user doesn't have javascript enabled whats the best way to redirect them to my PHP page for composing and sending a message?

I'm assuming the jquery code takes highest priority since it's client side but then do I wrap my php code in  tags?

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I think you're confusing server-side and client-side code.  What you do is you have a normal HTML form.  You have JS override the submit functionality, and do whatever.  If JS is off, the form would submit normally.

Comment: Do you have users that actually disable javascript?

Comment: `<noscript>Time to upgrade your browser</noscript>`

Comment: is this really worth worrying about anymore? this is only 1% max of users http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/

Comment: Why avoid javascript? It's almost a requirement with the web applications of today. No point in creating a mountain to climb over when there's really no need.

Comment: Evan @AdamRackis jrummel can we stop trolling and actually write HTML pages that actually work. non-javascript support is still important, it's called _not breaking_ the bloody web.

Comment: @Rocket If I were forced to care about those users, I would have the site gracefully downgrade to a less featured and less cool experience with plain, boring html.

Comment: To everyone saying this issue isn't worth working on.  What if I'm using NoScript, and I don't allow your site?

Comment: @jrummell: That's exactly what I was suggesting in my 1st comment :-P

Comment: @Raynos - not trolling, just joking.  Whether you support no script pages should be a decision based not on ideological nonsense like "breaking the web", but by simple economic considerations: how much will it cost to put the extra effort in, and how many customers will I lose if I don't.

Comment: According to google analytics...30% of my daily users do not have javascript enabled.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that we should shun NoScript users, I'm just saying that you should make sure that you actually have NoScript or non-js friendly users before going down this road :).

Comment: @AdamRackis to an extend, However there are limits, like making sure page loading and navagation works without javascript. Also simple forms like login, sign up, feedback etc should just work without javascript. There are certain things HTML is good at, re-inventing them using a custom javascript layer is stupid.

Comment: @AdamRackis $(function(){ var oops = "why doesn't my website work".;});


I can think of much less esoteric reasons to present functional HTML.

Comment: @Raynos - spending cold, hard, green cash (which is what a developer's time is) on a potentially tiny % of your customers is stupid.  BTW, even Stack Overflow requires JS.

Comment: @Paul that's a totally non trivial amount. So it's worth while to do this.

Comment: @AdamRackis Stack overflow doesn't require JS to view questions. And besides the idea that non-javascript supports "takes extra money/time" is also trolls. Any competent developer would be doing progressive enhancement anyway.

Comment: @Paul - are you sure that's not including bots and stuff?  According to Yahoo it's 1%  http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/

Comment: @AdamRackis: `Stack Overflow works **best** with JavaScript enabled`.

Comment: @Rayno - a competent developer is maximizing profit for his company.  Period.  If that means progressively enhancing the site to fallback gracefully for non-script browsers, then great.  It **always** takes more time to code for one default path for the form to post to, and then provide an ajax path / partial response.  If a certain business decides that its customers browse with script enabled, then there's no reason to support the former.

Comment: @Rocket - I've never browsed SO without JS, I was basing my statement off this meta post  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: @AdamRackis a competent business man maximizes profit for his company. A competent programmer writes a high quality tool or application. Profit is not the end goal, quality is. From quality comes profit. It doesn't neccessarily take more time to code multiple paths, it may take more time to support multiple browsers on the partial path.

Comment: Please take the discussion about whether or not Paul actually *has* to do this to chat.  This is becoming a prolonged discussion that is not directly related to the question at hand (which is about the how *not the why*) and detracts from the questions and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what I would do here is take advantage of the onclick event of the button. You can use javascript or jquery to return false. If the browser has javascript turned off, the form will then be submitted.

```
<input type="button" onclick="return btnClick()" value="submit">
```

and then in your javascript something like

```
function btnClick(){
    //do ajaxy stuff
    return cancelEvent()
}
function cancelEvent()
{
    if (window.event) window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: avoid in line DOM0 event handlers. Also please make you `cancelEvent` function work. you need to call `event.stopPropagation()` because `return false` doesn't do anything in DOM event handlers (it's a non-standard extension)

Comment: It does work, I pulled it from one of my working solutions. return false works everywhere that if (window.event) window.event.cancelBubble = true doesn't. Try it before suggesting that it doesn't work.

Comment: Where in DOM3 events or DOM4 does it say that `return false` from an event listener will invoke `event.stopPropagation()`. It's a non-standard extension which may be removed at any time.

Comment: Note that I meant `event.preventDefault();` not `event.stopPropagation();`. My mistake.

Comment: That'll work perfectly.  I'll handle my jquery modal dialog if enabled and if not I'll include a href tag. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is make a normal HTML form:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST" id="sendMessage">
   <input id="msg" name="message" type="text" />
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then use jQuery to override the submit feature:

```
$('#sendMessage').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // Stops the browser from submitting the form normally
  // Do stuff...
});
```

So, if JavaScript is enabled, jQuery will handle form submission.  It it's not enabled, the browser will POST the form normally.